# Ejecución archivo PHP al refrescar el navegador

Tags: php, html

Antes de nada, estoy aprendiendo con esto de la programación en PHP y con HTML.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con HTML y PHP mediante una API de UniFi.
Este proyecto se encarga de interactuar con la API ya creada a través de unos ficheros PHP que yo he creado.

Digamos que tenemos la siguiente estructura:

```
/servidorWeb/index.html
/servidorWeb/stat_auths2.php
/servidorWeb/create.php
```

Mediante el `index.html` con un formulario introduzco los datos necesarios para realizar la comprobación. Si los datos introducidos son correctos el `stat_auths2.php` llama al `create.php`.

El `create.php` interactúa con la API y una base de datos.

Hasta aquí todo correcto (Todo funciona correctamente), pero una vez ejecutado todo si refrescas la página (F5) vuelve a ejecutarse el código de `create.php` volviendo a llamar a la API y necesito evitar eso.

¿Cómo puedo evitar esto?

Os dejo el código de ejemplo por si ayuda:

#### - index.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/browser/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/browser/static/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <title> Formulario para cambio de vales </title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#F0F3F4;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p></p>
    <center>
        <img src="foto1.png" alt="Solvetic">
        <br>
        <p></p>

        <legend>Formulario para cambio de vales</legend>
    </center>


    <p></p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <form action="/browser/stat_auths-2.php" method="post">
                <center>
                    <p>Introduzca el vale anterior: <input type="text" name="voucher_input" required></p>

                    <p> ¿Cual es tu habitación? </p>
                    <select name="room" size=12 required>  

                        <optgroup label="BLOQUE 1"> 
                            <option value="BLOQUE 1-H2">BLOQUE 1-H2</option> 

                        </optgroup>   
                        <optgroup label="BLOQUE 2">
                            <option value="BLOQUE 2-H1">BLOQUE 2-H1</option> 

                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="BLOQUE 3"> 

                            <option value="BLOQUE 3-H1">BLOQUE 3-H1</option>
                        </optgroup> 
                        <optgroup label="BLOQUE 4">
                            <option value="BLOQUE 4-H1">BLOQUE 4-H1</option> 

                        </optgroup> 

                    </select>

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
                </center>  
            </form> 

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <p></p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><center><img src="foto2.png" alt="Solvetic">
            <p> Para incidencias:</p>
            <p>correo@correo.com</p>
        </center></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="/browser/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>      
    <script src="/browser/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### - stat_auths2.php

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/browser/static/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/browser/static/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <title> Formulario para cambio de vales </title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#F0F3F4;">

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p></p>
  <center>
   <img src="foto1.png" alt="Solvetic">
   <br>
   <p></p>

   <legend>Formulario para cambio de vales</legend>
 </center>


 <p></p>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<br>

<p></p>

<center>
  <H4>
    <?php



    $origen = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $currentDate=date("Y/m/d h:i");
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($currentDate);



    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');


    require_once('config.php');
//error_reporting(0);


    $site_id = '';
    $controlleruser = '';
    $controllerpassword = '';
    $controllerurl = '';
    $site_id = '';
    $controllerversion = '';
    $findThisVoucher= $_POST['voucher_input'];
    $room = $_POST['room'];


    $unifi_connection           = new UniFi_API\Client($controlleruser, $controllerpassword, $controllerurl, $site_id, $controllerversion);
    $set_debug_mode             = $unifi_connection->set_debug($debug);
    $loginresults               = $unifi_connection->login();


    $findThisVoucher  = str_replace('-', '', $findThisVoucher); 

    $longitud_voucher = strlen($findThisVoucher); 

    if ($longitud_voucher < 10) { 
      echo "El vale $findThisVoucher no se ha introducido correctamente, tiene menos de 10 carácteres. ";
      $findThisVoucher = false;
    }
    if ($longitud_voucher > 10) { 
      echo "El vale $findThisVoucher no se ha introducido correctamente, tiene mas de 10 carácteres. ";
      $findThisVoucher = false;




      $data_auths            = $unifi_connection->stat_auths();              
      $status_find       = json_encode($data_auths, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  
      $json_mac              = json_decode($status_find);                    
      $mac_device            = null;                                        


      $data_guests       = $unifi_connection->list_guests();             
      $mac_find              = json_encode($data_guests, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
      $json_expired          = json_decode($mac_find);                      



      foreach ($json_mac as $record) {
    $num_voucher = $record->voucher_code; // por cada posicion recorrida almacenamos en $num_voucher el voucher_code del array

    if ($num_voucher === $findThisVoucher) { 

      break;

    }
  }

  if ($mac_device === null) { 
    echo "no se ha encontrado el vale o no está activo";
    $note   = '[Cambio de vale ERROR] ' . $room . ' ' . $currentDate . ' >> C:\xampp\logs\log-API.txt [not found] ' ;
    exec("echo $note");
  } else {
    foreach ($json_expired as $record) { 
      $mac = $record->mac;
      $status_expired = $record->expired;

      if ($mac_device === $mac) { 

        if ($status_expired != null) {              
          echo "El vale no está activo";
          $note   = '[Cambio de vale ERROR] ' . $room . ' ' . $currentDate . ' >> C:\xampp\logs\log-API.txt [not active] ' . $findThisVoucher . ' ' .$mac_device  ;
          exec("echo $note");
        } else {
          echo "El vale está activo"; 
                $unifi_connection->unauthorize_guest($mac_device); // desautorizamos el dispositivo
       include 'create.php';
       break;
     }
   }
 }
}
?>
</H4>

<form action="http://172.26.100.250:8081/index.html">
  <input type="submit" value="volver" />
</form>

</center>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><center><img src="foto2.png" alt="Solvetic">
    <p> Para incidencias:</p>
    <p>correo@correo.com</p>
  </center></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>


<script src="/browser/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>      
<script src="/browser/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### - create.php

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/browser/static/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/browser/static/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <title> Formulario para cambio de vales </title>
</head>
<center>


    <H4>
        <?php
        if($origen!= "/browser/stat_auths-2.php"){
            header("location:http://172.26.100.250:8081/inde2.html");
        }

        require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

        /
        require_once('config.php');


        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
        $currentDate    = date("Y/m/d h:i"); 
        $datetime1       = new DateTime($currentDate); 
        $datetime2       = new DateTime('2018-07-15'); 

        $interval        = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
        $days            = $interval->format('%a'); 
        $date_limit      = 60*24*$days; 



        $voucher_expiration = $date_limit;

        /
        $voucher_count = 1;


        $site_id                    = '';
        $controlleruser             = '';
        $controllerpassword         = '';
        $controllerurl              = '';
        $site_id                    = '';
        $controllerversion          = '';


        $quota  = 1;
        $note   = 'Vale-API, ' . $room . ' ' . $currentDate  ;
        $up     = null;
        $down   = null; 
        $MBytes = null;


        $unifi_connection = new UniFi_API\Client($controlleruser, $controllerpassword, $controllerurl, $site_id, $controllerversion);
        $set_debug_mode   = $unifi_connection->set_debug($debug);
        $loginresults     = $unifi_connection->login();


        $voucher_result = $unifi_connection->create_voucher($voucher_expiration, $voucher_count, $quota, $note, $up, $down, $MBytes);


        $vouchers = $unifi_connection->stat_voucher($voucher_result[0]->create_time);


        $data_vouchers  = json_encode($vouchers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $json_voucher   = json_decode($data_vouchers);  


        foreach ($json_voucher as $record) {
            $num_voucher = $record->code; 

        }
        /
        $note   = '[Cambio de vale OK] ' . $room . ' ' . $currentDate . ' ' .  $findThisVoucher . ' ' .$mac_device .' ' . $num_voucher .' >> C:\xampp\logs\log-API.txt';
        exec("echo $note");


        echo "Se ha anulado y creado el siguiente: $num_voucher ";

        ?>
    </H4>



</center>
<body>
    <script src="/browser/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>      
    <script src="/browser/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Investiga una técnica llamada "post-redirect-get" (y de paso, la vida entre los distintos métodos / verbos HTTP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una sesión que guarde los datos del formulario y agrega un condicional de que si la variable `$_SESSION` contiene los datos, no vuelva a cargar el formulario, sino que utilice estos datos.

Para ahcerlo debes usar la función `session_start();` y puede comenzar a almacenar datos en dicha variable. Cuando quieras que los datos se eliminen, utiliza la función `session_destroy()` y todo se borrará y comenzará nuevamente el proceso.

Acá te pongo un ejemplo:

```
session_start();

    $_SESSION['datos_ok'] = true;

    if(isset($_SESSION['datos_ok'])){
        //tomar los datos de la variable $_SESSION
    }else{
        //tomas los datos de la variable $_POST o $_REQUEST
    }
```

Luego determinas en qué momento quieres que se eliminen los datos de sesión y en ese lugar pones simplemente la función `session_destroy()`.